# search within pdf structure without including the comments

Tags: python, pdf, comments

I want to search for keywords within pdf file using python .I don't want to search within the comments (after % ) . when I look for the keyword "entry" for example I don't want to include the one after %.

1 0 obj   % entry point

could any one help me with this ?